# load php data into an element with parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

this is my first time using stackoverflow.com, i almost give up with code problem, i do hope someone could help me to solve my code problem.

here is my problem, i have 2 tables, i load data from database to the 1st table (onload), and i want to have an onclick event on the data row to load the 2nd table, and i want to use the clicked value as a parameter to load the 2nd table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center">empid</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">empname</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<?php                               
include ("dbconn.php");
$sql = "select * from employee";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>

    <tr>
        <td><a href="#"><u><?php echo $row["empid"]; ?></u></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["empname"]; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $row["age"]; ?></td>     
    </tr>

<?php
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>

    </tbody>
</table>

<! -- additional table -->                  
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>employee name</th>
            <th>position</th>
            <th>salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbl">

<?php       

$sql = "select * from employee_salary where empid = $empid";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
                        <tr>
                          <th><?php echo $row["empname"]; ?></th>
                                                    <td><?php echo $row["position"]; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row["salary"]; ?></td>
                        </tr>
<?php
}
mysqli_close($conn);

?>  

    </tbody>
</table>


  </body>
</html>
```

anyone help me please... thank you.

Comment: did you tried something or where is your click event function?

Comment: sorry for my bad english, maybe the 1st question is confusing. My purpose is when i click the employee id link on the 1st table, dynamicaly call the php code and put it into element <tbody id="tbl">.

Comment: Still i am not clear exactly what are you want to do, you want to hide second table initially and then on click of any row of first table, second table should be visible, is that you want?

Comment: yes Jigar7521, thats exactly what i want to do...but i dont know how to pass the value from the first table to load data on the 2nd table... would you please help me?

Comment: i would like to thank you for Happy Coding for the reply and bunch of thank for Jigar7521 for giving me a knowledge to start. i had found my solution after combined some information from Jigar7521 and internet. i just added 1 line code "$empid = $_REQUEST['empid'];" to getdata.php.... have a nice day all ... :D

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following step : 
1) Here your initial page code :

```
<body>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center">empid</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">empname</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<?php                               
include ("dbconn.php");
$sql = "select * from employee";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>

    <tr onclick="getDetail('<?php echo $row["empid"]; ?>')">
        <td><a href="#"><u><?php echo $row["empid"]; ?></u></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["empname"]; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $row["age"]; ?></td>     
    </tr>

<?php
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>

    </tbody>
</table>

<! -- additional table -->                  
<table id="secondTable" style="display:none;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>employee name</th>
            <th>position</th>
            <th>salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbl">



    </tbody>
</table>


  </body>
</html>
```

2) Now make one ajax call on click of employee id like :

```
<script>
     function getDetail(id){
        $.post( "../ajax/getData.php", {emp_id:id},function(data){
          $('#secondTable').show();
          $('#secondTable tbody').html(data);
        });
     }
</script>
```

3) Here your getData.php file:

```
    <?php                               
    include ("dbconn.php");
    $emp_id = $_POST['emp_id'];
    $sql = "select * from employee where empid= $emp_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $data = '';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {


        $data.='<tr>
            <td><a href="#"><u>'.$row["empid"].'</u></a></td>
            <td>'. $row["empname"].'</td> 
            <td>'. $row["age"].'</td>     
        </tr>';


    }
mysqli_close($conn);
echo $data; exit;
?>
```

Let me know if any query, Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you for you reply Jigar7521, i can understand your code even its hard for me, it almost solve, but there is a small touch i need... on getdata.php, i didnt see the parameter value (empid) to filter the data to load....

Comment: oops i am sorry Jigar7521, i didnt notice ... sorry for my bad... yes your solution is the best for me ... thank you once again... have a nice day ... :)